# Bandwidth issues on Google Cloud Run FastApi

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, fastapi, google-cloud-run

I've been deploying a fastapi app on Google Cloud Run. Some of the api endpoints involve hitting external websites and downloading data. I'm finding that my calls to these endpoints take a long time, and have been able to measure the time it takes to get the request back from these external sites to be 4-5 seconds. The data I'm getting back is around 3-7mb, not a ton. When I test it locally it's around 0.7 seconds. I created a compute engine instance with the same characteristics and a container from the same image and tested this endpoint, and it takes around 1 second.

My cloud run settings are mostly default, cpu should be 2 cores, memory 8G.
I know cold starts are a problem, but when I submit a request immediately after a previous one, it still takes 4-5 seconds. So regardless of cold start, the app pinging the site is the problem. Looking at CPU and memory metrics, nothing stands out, they don't go above 25%.

I'm serving the app via uvicorn with this line in my dockerfile `CMD uvicorn api:app --port $PORT --host 0.0.0.0`. I tried a couple different approaches here too, but because I tested serving it the same way in the compute engine instance, I don't think this is the problem.

The only thing I can think of is that I have settings limiting my bandwidth, but I can't find anything related to this. As far as I'm aware I should have a default of 1 Gbps, while it's looking like I'm downloading at less than 1Mbps. Any ideas?

Comment: 2 vCPUs is a small instance size. Try a much larger size to see if you can achieve the performance you require.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The network performance using the 2nd generation execution environment is improved. Try explicitly setting this in your Cloud Run service configuration: [image]

Comment: I think this solved it! I'd love to understand more about what this is doing under the hood - there's some information here https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-execution-environments?_ga=2.91410010.-1921768749.1700594348 but it's not deep. Anyway this reduced latency times to similar to what I have locally, so thank you!

Comment: Great that it worked, thanks for confirming.

I did find some more information about the 1st generation environment here: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#sandbox

It sounds like the use of the gVisor sandbox in the 1st gen environment is the culprit.